# Visual Studio 2019 mostrar referencias de una clase/metodo

Tags: visual-studio, .net

estoy buscando en VS2019 como hacer para que me muestre lo marcado en la imagenes, es una opcion que te muestra la referencias de una clase, en mi VS no me lo muestra asi, alguien sabe como habilitar?¿

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué edición estás utilizando?

Answer (score 1):

Puede personalizar las referencias para activarlos o desactivarlos desde:
**Herramientas** -> **Opciones** -> **Editor de texto** luego **Todos los idiomas** y **Lente de código** (CodeLens).
Activa el Check "Mostrar referencias".

Adjunto un pantallazo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).